# Computing some recursive functions in C

Tags: c, recursion

I am beginner at recursive function concepts..I have 2 problems to ask:

1. Given: **f(n) = n/2 if n is even, f(3n+1) if n is odd.**
   How can I write a recursive function to compute f(n)?
2. What problem do you notice in the following recursive function? Show 2 possible ways to correct it.

   ```
   int silly(int n )
   {
       if (n<= 0)
           return 1;
       else if (n%2==0)
           return n;
       else 
           silly(n-3);
   }
   ```

Comment: 1) use google and "Collatz in C" 2) are you sure you copied the program correctly, there is a lot of syntax problem before trying to solve the "recursion" problem.

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment. Some obvious issues in your code, which is what part 2 wants you to fix.

Comment: What are you doing with the return value from the recursive call to `silly()`? Nothing, and `silly()` returns without a value.

Comment: I have posted a full answer to homework before, only to find the OP has ungraciously deleted the question - to prevent classmates from seeing it?

Comment: Infinite recursion with the problem statement: start with n = 1, then f(3n+1) = f(4) is called. f(n/2) = f(2) is called, then f(n/2) = f(1) is called repeating the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

> `f(n) = n/2` if `n` is even, `f(3n+1)` if `n` is odd.

A recursive function to do that is something like this pseudo-code:

```
def f(n):
    if f % n == 0:  return f(n/2)     # assume integer division.
    return f(3*n-1)
```

However, given that *every* integral number is either even or odd (even and odd have no meaning but for integers), then there's no terminating condition. You'll soon run out of stack space, unless your compiler is smart enough to turn that recursive function into an iterative one, in which case you'll run for eternity.

The usual problem statement of that type has a terminating condition like "stop when it reaches zero", which would be the following modification:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:     return 0
    if f % n == 0: return f(n/2)
    return f(3*n-1)
```

In fact, usually you're required to measure the number of *operations* to reach zero, which would be:

```
def f(n, count):
    if n == 0:     return count
    if f % n == 0: return f(n/2, count+1)
    return f(3*n-1, count+1)
```

In terms of the recursive function, the problem is that not all paths return a value. You can fix that by ensuring they do. This can be done by simply prefixing `silly (n-3)` with `return` but, since I prefer not to have all those unnecessary `if/else` blocks, it's cleaner to write like this:

```
int silly (int n) {
    if (n <= 0)     return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return n;
    return silly (n-3);
}
```